# Display a NumberPicker on an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, numberpicker

I am trying to display a NumberPicker on an AlertDialog.
The AlertDialog works, but it doesn't show the NumberPicker.

Here is my code

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(360);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Changing the Hue");
    builder.setMessage("Choose a value :");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialogHost.onPositiveButton(numberPicker.getValue());
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialogHost.onCancelButton();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never set the view of the Dialog.

```
builder.setView(numberPicker);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need including 2 lines:

1. `builder.setView(numberPicker);`
2. `return build.show()`

So, the code must be like this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(360);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(numberPicker);    
    builder.setTitle("Changing the Hue");
    builder.setMessage("Choose a value :");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        dialogHost.onPositiveButton(numberPicker.getValue());
    }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        dialogHost.onCancelButton();
    }
    });
   builder.create();
   return builder.show();
}
```